# My game wont go to my function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Well here's the problem my game() function wont go to my firstlevel() function and just keeps says process exited with exit code 0 And I have no clue why I even tried changing the function name And still no luck I truly  have no clue what to do I am just a beginner...

code:

```
import winsound
import random as ran
import pickle


profile = {}


def fightsound():
    winsound.PlaySound('fight2.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)



def ranking():
    if profile['xp'] >= 20:
        profile['level'] += 1
        if profile['xp'] >= 50:
            profile['level'] += 1
            if profile['xp'] >= 100:
                profile['level'] += 1
                game()
            else:
                game()
        else:
            game()
    else:
        game()


def play_bgmusic():
    winsound.PlaySound('mk.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)


def load_game():
    global profile
    profile = pickle.load(open("save.txt", "rb"))
    game()


def fatality():
    winsound.PlaySound('fatal2.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)


def game():
    global profile
    print("Player: " + profile['player'])
    print("XP: ", profile['xp'])
    print("Level: ", profile['level'])
    print("win: ", profile['win'])
    print("loss: ", profile['loss'])
    if profile['level'] >= 1:
        print("1.) The ogre king...")
        if profile['level'] >= 2:
            print("2.) The realm of the witch!")
    y = input("Select an option -> ")
    if y == 1:
        firstlevel()


def firstlevel():
    global profile
    fightsound()
    enemyhp = 50
    hp = 100
    while enemyhp > 0:
        print("Your hp: ", hp, " Enemy hp: ", enemyhp)
        input("Press enter to attack...")
        damage = ran.randint(0, 25)
        enemyhp -= damage
        damage = ran.randint(0, 25)
        hp -= damage
        if hp <= 0:
            profile['xp'] += 5
            profile['loss'] += 1
            pickle.dump(profile, open("save.txt", "wb"))
            print("You died, press enter to continue...")
            game()
    fatality()
    profile['xp'] += 10
    profile['win'] += 1
    pickle.dump(profile, open("save.txt", "wb"))
    input("You win! Press enter to continue...")
    ranking()


def new_game():
    global profile
    player = input("Enter a player name -> ")
    profile['player'] = player
    profile['xp'] = 0
    profile['level'] = 1
    profile['win'] = 0
    profile['loss'] = 0
    pickle.dump(profile, open("save.txt", "wb"))
    game()


def main():
    play_bgmusic()
    print(20 * "-")
    print("|                  |")
    print("| 1.) New Game     |")
    print("| 2.) Load Game    |")
    print("| 3.) Credits      |")
    print("|                  |")
    print(20 * "-")

    x = int(input("Select an option -> "))

    if x == 1:
        new_game()
    if x == 2:
        load_game()
    if x == 3:
        pass

main()
```

Comment: Also I am going to fix my ranking function but that's beside the point

Comment: So are you sure that y is ever equal to 1? Try printing out y and seeing if you get what you want.

Comment: No wonder it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is these three lines:

```
y = input("Select an option -> ")
if y == 1:
    firstlevel()
```

When you get input, it will come back as a string. You are comparing the string `"1"` to the integer `1`. The two are not equal, so `firstlevel()` is never called.

You should convert the string to an integer, or change the integer to a string, so that you are comparing two objects of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna bet it's cause `y` isn't what you think it is. Try printing it out or putting a breakpoint on it to make sure it is an integer with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
y = input("Select an option -> ")
if y == 1:
```

`input()` returns a string, so it will never be equal to the integer `1`. Simply use `int()` on `y` before your comparison and you'll be good to go.